# Diagrama EDR criação de uma loja online

Tags: modelo-relacional

Estou tentado criar um EDR diagrama, creio que da parte dos clientes tenho as ligações bem feitas, mas do lado do administrador que tem acesso a tudo, informação do produto, detalhes das encomendas e perfil dos clientes. Mas estou um pouco perdida em como estabelecer a relação vejam a imagem[image: Diagram ERD]

Comment: E por qual razão o administrador deveria estar presente em seu modelo de dados?